# Mongoose .save reverting back to original value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple for loop that is just incrementing a value in the Schema. I simply call `findOne` using a document's `_id`. Update the Doc's property and call `.save`. But I am noticing it never increments, it just goes back to 0 and so the value never goes above 1.

Find/Update Code

```
try {
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const find = async () =>  {
      const found = await JobStatus.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id)})
        .exec().then(function(doc) {
          console.log("Before "+i+" : " +doc.number_of_items_processed)
          doc.number_of_items_processed += 1
          doc.save();
        console.log("After "+i+" : " +doc.number_of_items_processed)
      })
    }
    find()
  }//for(....)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

This is the the console output:

```
Before 0 : 0
After 0 : 1
Before 2 : 0
After 2 : 1
Before 1 : 0
After 1 : 1
Before 3 : 0
After 3 : 1
Before 5 : 0
After 5 : 1
Before 4 : 0
After 4 : 1

db.jobstatuses.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a3c981cbd8f4128c48d8207"),
        "number_of_items_submitted" : 5059,
        "number_of_items_processed" : 1,//STARTS OUT WITH 0
        "time_completed" : null,
        "job_outcome" : "Submitted",
        "job_errors" : null,
        "time_submitted" : ISODate("2017-12-22T05:29:00.530Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Try this

```
try {
  for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const find = async () =>  {
      const found = await JobStatus.update({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id)},{$inc:{number_of_items_processed:1}})
        .exec().then(function(doc) {
            console.log("Number of items processed"+ doc.number_of_items_processed);
         })
    }
    find()
  }//for(....)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

//In your approach

```
  try{
   for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     const find = async () =>  {
     const found = await JobStatus.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id)}).exec();    
      console.log("Before "+i+" : " +found.number_of_items_processed)
        found.number_of_items_processed += 1
        found.save();
       console.log("After "+i+" : " +found.number_of_items_processed) 
     }
     find()
    }//for(....)
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
```

}

Comment: Thanks. This work but I am just wondering what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: async issue have in your approach

Comment: sorry i m busy..i will correct my code and find what is issue in your approach.